# Sprites with html and css

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I've got some code that uses sprites, this is designed to look like a horizontal navigation bar.  My question is: for my code shown below, does this method actually cause the end user to download the png image 8 times or just the once.

And if it is actually once, is there a better method to do this?

CSS Code

```
#facebook, #twitter, #linkedin, #googleplus {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#facebook {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") 0 0;
}

#twitter {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") -64px 0;
}

#linkedin {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") -128px 0;
}

#googleplus {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") -192px 0;
}

#facebook:hover {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") 0 -64px;
}

#twitter:hover {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") -64px -64px;
}

#linkedin:hover {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") -128px -64px;
}

#googleplus:hover {
    background: url("images/sprite.png") -192px -64px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<nav>
    <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>
    <a id="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com"></a>
    <a id="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com"></a>
    <a id="googleplus" href="https://plus.google.com"></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request will happen only once and the image will be cached. The image **will be redrawn** again, but not by requesting the server. It requests the server only once. But it is always a good practise to have the `url()` in the master class or a single instance:

```
#facebook, #twitter, #linkedin, #googleplus {
  background: url("images/sprite.png");
}
```

Moreover it is better to use `background-position` alone, instead of `background`, also you don't need to reuse the `background: url()` again in `:hover`.

Comment: Thanks this makes the code look much neater.  Now I've made your suggested changes, when you say the image will be redrawn again, I'm just curious does this mean the entire sprite image is drawn or loaded 4/8 times, or drawn once and the other bits outside the shown area are just hidden from view.

Comment: @smally Well, every rendering process is a redraw right, I meant that. The main thing is that, the browser **will not** request for a new image from the server. Take in this way, when the image has changed at the moment, browser has requested fro the first three `url()`s and when the fourth one is parsed, new image will not be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

It'll be downloaded only once, and this is the main reason to use CSS sprite sheets, it will be downloaded once only and with only one HTTP request instead of 8 HTTP requests if you provide an image for each icon with normal and hover states.

And no, this is how it is implemented and you're doing it correctly.

**Resources:**

1. https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/
2. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS

---

**Edit:**
As [Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar) mentioned you only write the `url()` once for all corresponding rules and with `background-position` shift the image either horizontally or vertically depending on your image

Comment: I didn't quote anything from anywhere I just wrote what I've read few years ago and I put w3schools as a *second* link but didn't quote anything, Also I know some people are anti-w3schools and in some cases they're right but that doesn't mean that ALL info from w3schools are wrong!

Comment: Okay. Cool. Still, it is better to avoid the use of that site.

Comment: He's free to choose from resources I've posted

Comment: My humble request is please don't guide people by showing links to W3Schools. I do understand they are good in a few. Still.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion which I appreciate and I'm sure the OP would read your comments

Comment: Sure.. Thanks for understanding what I meant. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Is their a reason I shouldn't use w3schools? I'm still a beginner therefore I use that site quite a lot.

Comment: You welcome, before on some w3schools webpages there were wrong or misleading information and developers started warning others about them, although things have been changed since then, w3schools still has bad reputation, read answers in here http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/why-shouldnt-i-use-w3schools-as-reference and this